# class Validator in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading the rails guides. I am trying create a class Validator but I get the following error message in console

uninitialized constant Product::GoodnessValidator

model product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_with GoodnessValidator

end
```

I create a folder inside the app called validators and then I create the file goodness_validator.rb

```
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
      def validate(record)
        if record.amount == 12
          record.errors[:base] << "The amount musn't be 12"
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails loads only specific folders (the default folders) from the `app` directory. If you want to add a new subfolder (like `validators`) and you want Rails to load files from that folder, then you have to configure that by adding the following line to your `config/application.rb`:

```
# in config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/validators)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by adding following line at top of your `user.rb`

```
require 'validators/goodness_validator'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is load code in sequence, so you should put the GoodnessValidator on the front.

```
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
      def validate(record)
        if record.amount == 12
          record.errors[:base] << "The amount musn't be 12"
        end
      end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_with GoodnessValidator

end
```

You can have a try.